# Не могу понять в чем ошибка при переборе матрицы PASCAL

Tags: pascal

Матрица просто не меняется, только вместо правого верхнего угла появляется ноль, а она должна поворачиваться на 90 градусов влево

```
program n_a;
const n=5;m=5;
var a:array[1..n,1..m]of integer;
var b:array[1..n,1..m]of integer;
i,j,x,y:integer;
begin

x:=1;
y:=5;
//автозаполнение матрицы
for i:=1 to n do begin
    for j:=1 to m do begin
        a[i,j]:=random(90)+10;
        write(a[i,j]:4);
        b[i,j]:=a[i,j];
    end;
    writeln;
end;


//поварачиваем на 90 градусов влево
for i:=n downto 1 do
Inc(x);
begin
    for j:=1 to 5 do
    b[i,y]:=a[y,i];
    Dec(y);
    if x > 5 then
        x := 1;
    if y < 1 then
        y := 5;
end;




//вывод 
writeln('Результат');
for i:=1 to n do
begin
for j:=1 to n do
write(b[i,j]:4);
writeln;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Мне не столь важно получить готовый рабочий код, мне важнее понять в чем ошибка у меня

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0):

```
program n_a;

const 
  n = 5;
  m = 5;

var 
  a: array [1..n, 1..m] of integer;
  b: array [1..n, 1..m] of integer;
  i, j: integer;

begin
  x := 1;
  y := 5;

  randomize;
  // автозаполнение матрицы
  for i := 1 to n do begin
    for j := 1 to m do begin
      a[i, j] := random(90) + 10;
      write(a[i, j]:4);
      b[i, j] := a[i, j];
    end;
    writeln;
  end;

  writeln;

  // поварачиваем на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки
  for j := m downto 1 do begin
    for i := 1 to n do begin
      b[m - j + 1, i] := a[i, j];
      write(b[m - j + 1, i]:4);
    end;
    writeln;
  end;
end.
```

> ```
>   15  35  74  43  48
>   20  25  73  42  94
>   53  72  80  92  11
>   67  48  40  33  95
>   80  51  71  97  38
>
>   48  94  11  95  38
>   43  42  92  33  97
>   74  73  80  40  71
>   35  25  72  48  51
>   15  20  53  67  80
> ```

Comment: Процитирую ТС - "Мне не столь важно получить готовый рабочий код, **мне важнее понять в чем ошибка** у меня"

Comment: @Kromster, да, я умею читать. Что автор поймет из предложения "ошибка в работе с индексами матрицы" без конкретного примера? А конкретный пример и будет являться решением.